# asp TextBox with TextMode="Date" How to copy the date?

Tags: asp.net, textbox, copy-paste

Is it possible to copy the date as a string to the clipboard? When we used DevExpress textbox, we were able to highlight entire date-field and copy. Now after we changed it to asp:TextBox (TextMode="Date"), we can't. The right-click context menu doesn't have any copy menu, and the left-click just displays the calendar.
[image]

Any suggest to achieve it is appreciated.

Comment: Well, you can hit ctrl-a, and then ctrl-c while in the text box to copy the current date. However, I suspect adding a right click "custom" menu with a copy option would be better, since most users would not think of hitting ctrl-a, and then ctrl-c. Busy day, but maybe this evening, we could try and cook up adding a right click custom menu with a copy, and maybe even a cut option.

Comment: @albert, Thank you. I didn't even know ctrl+a followed by ctrl+c would do. If you can show, how to hook up the right-click menu, that would be great. If not, would you put "ctrl+a followed by ctrl+c" as a proposed solution?

Comment: I think better then "text to tell user about ctrl-a"? See the code below, a small button beside the text box can "copy" the text box content into your paste buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so say this text box, and beside the text box, we have a button.

```
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" TextMode="date" ClientIDMode="Static">
        </asp:TextBox>
         <button id="mycopy" type="button"
            onclick="copyt();return false"
            >Copy</button>

        <script>

            function copyt() {
                console.log('start')
                var mytext = document.querySelector('#TextBox1').value
                navigator.clipboard.writeText(mytext)
                alert("you can now ctrl-v -- copy text = " + mytext)


            }

        </script>
```

So, the above will "copy" the contents of the text box into your paste buffer.

Of course, we could I suppose if you have font-awesome, then have a button like this:

```
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" TextMode="date" ClientIDMode="Static">
        </asp:TextBox>
         <button id="mycopy" type="button"
            onclick="copyt();return false"
            ><span class="fa fa-clipboard" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>

        <script>

            function copyt() {
                console.log('start')
                var mytext = document.querySelector('#TextBox1').value
                navigator.clipboard.writeText(mytext)
                alert("text = " + mytext)


            }
```

The result is now this:

[image]

And to be fair, one probably should remove the "alert" command in above.

As I suggested, another idea would be a custom right click context menu. However, that will require a good deal of code, and probably best to adopt some JavaScript library for this purpose. I did "look" for some examples, but the resulting code for a custom context menu was not all that clean. Hence, keeping this simple, the above looks to be about the least effort for the desired result.

Comment: Thank you soooooooooo much!!! I will use this approach and in some places where there are lots of textbox's, I will also put a note that "Use ctrl+A -> ctrl+C" for those who love the keyboard instead of the mouse-click.